# How can I extend the partial DateTime struct to add new static methods?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

I would like to add a static method to the `DateTime` struct that returns the number of days in a year.

In [this answer to a similar but much older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1188231/11808605), the answerer writes:

> "You cannot add methods to an existing type unless the existing type is marked as partial, you can only add methods that appear to be a member of the existing type through extension methods."

And proceeds to define an extension method to suit the asker's needs.

However, this was in 2009 so I'm wondering if things have changed. From [the implementation of DateTime](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/DateTime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b) in .NET Core, it seems like `DateTime` it is in fact a `partial struct`.

I tried to implement my method like this:

```cs
namespace MyApplication.MyNamespace
{
    public readonly partial struct DateTime
    {
        public static int DaysInYear(int year)
            => IsLeapYear(year) ? 366 : 365;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Changing the code to use `DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)` does not compile either. Changing the file's namespace to `System` corrupts all `System.DateTime` instances in the rest of my code.

Is there a way to extend the `DateTime` struct so I can call e.g. `DateTime.DaysInYear(2021)` in my code?

PLEASE NOTE THAT I'M NOT ASKING TO CREATE AN EXTENSION METHOD ON JUST ANY `DateTime` OBJECT, I WOULD LIKE IT TO BE AN EXPLICIT STATIC METHOD ON THE `DateTime` STRUCT

Comment: You're looking for extensions methods just add a parameter to your method (this DateTime date)

Comment: `I'm wondering if things have changed` there's no reason to. Using extension methods is far easier than a hypothetical `partial` syntax. Besides, `partial` is already used for something completely different

Comment: @gunr2171 that would make it work on any `DateTime`, I was wondering if I could make it specifically work as a static method like `DateTime.IsLeapYear(int year)` or `DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)`

Comment: All parts of a "partial" type must be defined in the same assembly, as partial is a language feature not a CLR feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858649/partial-classes-in-separate-dlls

Comment: @KlausGütter thanks, that actually is a useful link